# Why am I losing votes?

Tags: discussion, voting

I vote a lot: I've cast just over 12,000 total votes on Qs and As on ServerFault.  I'm also a persnickety sysadmin, so lately I've been tracking my vote totals and keeping track of whether I'm gaining on the couple of people who have voted more than I have.

For the past 3 weeks, I've noticed that my vote count goes down on the last day of the week.   For example, at 4pm local time on Friday (which is Saturday UTC 0000), I had 11985 votes.  Later, I cast my 40 votes for the day, but instead of 12025, my vote total is only 12015.  10 votes have disappeared.  (I keep forgetting to check my total when I start.)

So far, all these vanishing votes were cast before 1 Jan 2012: I've been tracking my weekly/monthly/quarterly votes, and those counts haven't gone down, just my all-time count.

I know that there is lots of cleanup of old questions going on on SF, so one possibility is that vote totals are recalculated at that time.  (UTC 0000 on Sat, the last day of the SE week.)

Is that what's happening?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions (it's not quite a duplicate)

Comment: Perhaps questions/answers on which you downvoted were deleted. And once a week the vote counts get recalculated.

Comment: I'm rather happy that downvotes on deleted answers are lost, so I can get my precious rep back. :-) And upvotes on posts that are later deleted *ought* to cost you something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eeeek! I'm missing 650 downvotes, and 300 upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90495/eeeek-im-missing-650-downvotes-and-300-upvotes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to (legitimately) "lose" a vote:

1. The question / answer you voted on gets deleted (as jonsca already pointed out).

   See [Eeeek! I'm missing 650 downvotes, and 300 upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90495/eeeek-im-missing-650-downvotes-and-300-upvotes).
2. You voted too many times on the same person's posts, the system calls shenanigans and voids your votes.

   For obvious reason, us mortals don't know exactly how it works.

   See:

   - [What is a vote fraud?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/what-is-a-vote-fraud)
   - [What are the mechanics of vote fraud handling (i.e. not the detection heuristics)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62066/what-are-the-mechanics-of-vote-fraud-handling-i-e-not-the-detection-heuristics)

Comment: Not 100% sure I'd describe the second one as "legitimately" losing the votes. If it's appropriate voting and the fraud detection pick it up it seems like a bug. If it's not appropriate voting then it's not legitimate.

Comment: @awoodland: You can easily trigger the fraud detection with appropriate voting. It happened to me at least once while browsing through the answers of a specific user. Not what I'd want to happen, but probably [status-bydesign].

Comment: The vote abuse issue needs another question...

Answer (score 2):

[This has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/154510).