# Are there "automatic" upvotes for high reputation users?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upvoting based on celebrity, too many upvotes (“excessive rep slurping”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/upvoting-based-on-celebrity-too-many-upvotes-excessive-rep-slurping)

I'm a bit confused. On this question [SQLite: execute case-sensitive LIKE query on a specific query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590700/sqlite-execute-case-sensitive-like-query-on-a-specific-query), the question was upvoted once in a minute or so.

An answered was then posted by a user with high reputation (50k+) explaining how to accomplish a case-insensitive query. Understandable mistake, as I didn't provide an example (I later did).

Their answer then (within seconds, or instantly) received an upvote, even though the answer was opposite of what I asked. The user later deleted their answer after I mentioned the question is about case-sensitive.

Do high reputation users automatically receive an upvote on their answers or the sort?

Comment: Why would you think someone would design things like that?

Comment: No, but sometimes upvoters misread the question the same way as the mistaken answerer.

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure about here, but reddit gives all users an automatic upvote on all their own submissions and comments.

Comment: I almost up-voted that answer myself before I caught myself.

Comment: There are no automatic votes like that here, no.

Answer (score 9):

No, there are no automatic upvotes.

*Sometimes* people may think that just because a user has a lot of reputation, they must know what they are talking about and upvote without reading the answer. That's wrong, but it happens.

Answer (score 6):

High reputation users don't receive automatic up votes by any means.  There are users who will up vote a high reputation user without diligently reading through it and the question.  With a lot of reputation usually comes a deal of confidence and people tend to believe them rather than verifying the answer.  This is likely the effect you are seeing

Can't say I'm completely innocent here.  I may have voted for a few Jon Skeet answers that I didn't totally understand. :)

Answer (score 5):

No. Everyone is treated the same here in terms of votes. Sometimes though, answers by high reputation users *seem* useful while they're actually not.

I'm pretty sure I could write an answer that has nothing to do with the question and get an upvote.

It's just a matter of writing style, making it look nice, and having enough reputation next to my avatar so others blindly trust you and cast an upvote without fully reading the answer (or understanding it, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Nobody is automatically upvoted. What may have happened is an accidental upvote or someone thought the answer made a good point and did not read the question clearly. As I have big fingers and use a cell phone to do my browsing I sometimes accidentally press things without even realizing. There is also people out there that just like to upvote. 
Referance: [How to know if I am a serial up voter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127742/how-to-know-if-i-am-a-serial-up-voter)