# Inconsistent CSS overlap on Stack Exchange notifications

Tags: bug, design, global-inbox

Sometimes when questions generate a lot of heat[,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196300/233688) or when a user is inactive for several days notifications can build up in the top bar like so:

[image: screen shot]

The issue is obviously when the number reaches the double digits, the numbers start to overlap with the "S" in "StackExchange". This was tested in Chrome v. 28. I haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: [Just for fun](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsNBC.png) (that's what you'll actually see when having 999 new items)

Comment: [Overflow!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i9HzD.png)

Comment: Down voter care to comment? I hope it isn't based on my post history; that wouldn't be fair.

Comment: @sha I wish you would start reading some of those mod messages I'm sending you!

Comment: If you have 25 notifications, you need to visit more often! ;)

Comment: What's going on? haha. I didn't know mods could send messages to users directly :D

Comment: @DauhFhauc they can but only as "official warning", usually before suspension - you don't want to get one! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This *should* be taken care of with our [shiny new top bar and multicollider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign), one of the major things it addresses is the definite lack of 'real estate' in the top bar.

I'm not sure if putting time into this is really going to pay off, since it's soon going to be replaced.

Comment: So it's a "will not fix because we're going to replace it soon anyway"?

Comment: Well, a dev would have to say that but my guess is _probably_ - as the fix _is_ basically replacing it (which also closes other things that can go wonky with it)