# Rate limiting on voting system

Tags: discussion, voting, rate-limiting

I recently came across a question and I saw the vote counter was updating as usual when people up-vote it.

But then I saw it was really another user upvoting, downvoting, upvoting, etc.

I joined in and had a blast. The other person would wait till I upvoted, then they would do do something to the vote count count, then I'd undo my upvote, and so on until they abandoned me :(

It was probably the most fun I've had at my job in awhile.

Shouldn't there be some form of rate limiting for this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to get a better job...

Comment: You're a troll dude, I remember the last question you asked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196300/i-gave-someone-200-rep-and-a-mortarboard-badge

Comment: @JoshC Well, he does seem to be deescalating, not escalating, so that's good.

Comment: Please do not bring up my past, it doesn't add to the discussion at hand. This did occur, and it could be an issue. There didn't seem to be any form of "rate-limiting" as @Servy correctly tagged the question. I do not understand these downvotes.

Comment: To anyone who thinks I'm a "troll", please visit my StackOverflow profile and see that I do contribute, flag posts, etc. Please look past one bad post that _most_ other people would have removed. I admit it was a bad question but get over it.

Comment: General rule, the answer to any question phrased as "Is it ok to ...." is always no

Comment: @DauhFhauc Only you and mods can see how many posts you've flagged, FYI.

Comment: I'll reformat the question, thanks for bringing it to my attention @RichardTingle

Comment: @DauhFhauc Your name is a good indicator that you're a troll too.

Comment: These comments aren't helping anyone: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19324524/814064

Comment: @JoshC People on reddit & other websites have horrible names and can give the best advice / etc. It isn't an indicator of anything. Again, visit my SO activity and you will see that I am not here to troll. Get off my case.

Comment: @dcaswell Exactly! That's why I made this post. Those comments brought this to my attention.

Comment: Could you clarify the specific benefits that would result from the Stack Exchange developers investing development effort into implementing such a rate-limiting system? I suppose there's some nonzero benefit, but I'm unconvinced that it's really worth it.

Comment: @Richard, that's a bad rule. "Is it ok ..." - "... to answer my own question", "... to close an old question as a duplicate of a newer better question", "... to unnaccept an answer", "... to delete an answer", "... to discuss poor security practices", "... to add comments to old posts", &c.

Comment: Well, votes should lock in after you've changed it say, 5 times. With the 5th time having an alert warning you that your final vote will be locked in unless the person edits their answer. This would cut this business easily without much effort on the developer side. I assume that Stack Exchange developers can script that one out in less than an hour. The benefits? Avoid the mild irritation that this causes to the _users_ as @Richard Tingle pointed out in his answer.

Comment: @jball general rules always have exceptions. Plus those questions have a different tone of voice. What you didn't hear the tone of voice? must get this keyboard fixed

Comment: @DauhFhauc [Code changes for a commercial product just aren't that simple](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx)

Comment: @Servy thanks for [the article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx) link but it is Microsoft that article is talking about. Friend interned there over the summer and it was meeting after meeting. I have a lot more hope for Stack Exchange developers.

Comment: @DauhFhauc The spirit applies in this context as well, even if all of the exact specifics don't.  A 5 minute code change is never just a 5 minute code change.

Comment: Ah, well I would up vote your comment @Servy but am barley staying afloat on Meta. Thanks for your input on the matter. I can see how it would be not worth it & they probably have enough servers to handle those occasions where click spamming occurs.

Comment: I didn't make an assertion as to whether it's worth it or not.  I'm personally on the fence.  My point is just that it's not trivial, cost wise, to implement it.  The benefits need to be enough to outweigh the more significant costs of the whole development cycle, rather than just the 5 minutes of dev time it would take to actually do the coding.

Comment: I wonder what your profile means when it says you accept all forms of criticism.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I quote you: "I wonder what your profile means when it says you accept all forms of criticism". I think it's pretty clear. What else could it mean? really?. People take a look at my username and perhaps my profile image and judge me. Always. This is a serious question that I've tried to keep light weight with a comment about my job. I'm sick of the people on this site and their attitudes towards newcomers. I get really infuriated when a moderator makes a comment as you have. Keep the comments on topic, please. You of all people should know this.

Comment: I think your comment there meshes with your history of interaction here. I'm wondering what your definitions are for 'all forms' and 'accept', particularly... because your behavior belies those words. And I have no idea what you mean by your name or image or job. Are you saying your expectation is those things affect how people see you? That's telling, in and of itself.

Answer (score 10):

This is mildly irritating for the post owner and serves no purpose, it should be resisted where possible just out of common sense whether a specific rule exists or not

Equally it's only mildly irritating and not worth development time to prevent, just be sensible and everyone is happy

Comment: Most things on this site are rate limited. 5 seconds between comment votes is my favorite. I don't see why I should be allowed to spam the vote button this way.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - How can you have a "favorite" impediment? That is my most hated one partially as deleting a comment comes under the same rate limit and partially as if you guess the 5 seconds wrong the timer resets and you must wait another 5 seconds. It is also the only one that I regularly encounter in normal usage (when cleaning up obsolete comments)