# Remove "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" for high rep users

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting, comment-voting

Often times there are multiple good comments on a question and you want to upvote them all. However, you can only do one every 5 seconds. I presume this is to prevent spam (especially from bots). However, based on how the rest of the site works, restrictions such as these are suppose to go away as the user gains more rep and becomes more trusted. So why not just have a point where the site says 'you are trusted enough to not upvote spam, so upvote as fast as you want`, though still have the limit of 30 per day?

Edit: Yeah, chaning the coment system to x every y seconds is an alternative answer, but Im something different - removal entirely based on rep. I think it would work better.

Comment: You really cannot wait a mere 5 seconds?

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 (I'd upvote, but I can't wait that long)

Comment: I don't mind this restriction but really wish that deleting comments wasn't included in it.

Comment: I think that the intention is not just to prevent spam, but to discourage going through and upvoting every comment without consideration, a temptation that's independent of rep. If it's worth upvoting, it's worth waiting 5 seconds.

Comment: @DavidRobinson If you upvoted every comment you didn't hurt anything, because comment upvotes don't really matter.

Comment: Even though this would be nice, comments are second-class citizens. They are used only to ask for clarification, and voting on them doesn't add anything to this site's quality. I don't believe SE will be implementing such a feature.

Comment: @David there is the total votes per day limit as well. On stack overflow it's not a problem but I hit it often on meta; so you couldn't up vote everything anyway

Comment: @Servy: You didn't hurt anything, but you also didn't *help* anything. One purpose of comment upvotes is to make some comments more visible than others (especially when the comment thread is long). If every comment is upvoted, this benefit is negated.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Exactly, so you did nothing.  Why is that such a problem that it's worth a feature just to prevent it?  If the "abuse" causes no real negative consequences, instead just doing nothing, and there are legitimate users hitting the rate limiting often, then the rate limiting itself isn't helping.

Comment: @Servy - Perhaps it's a performance thing? Every upvote is a database hit - and comments are probably not worth all the traffic from people who go upvote crazy.

Comment: @JDB - [Also a philosophical thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/why-is-there-a-12-closure-per-day-maximum/32202#32202)

Comment: @Laf "Second class" does not mean "worthless". Comments are used for much more than requesting clarification. If they *are* indeed "second class" then why rate-limit the removal of them? (also note that this message is not restricted to voting, but removal, perhaps that was overlooked. I misread the intent of the OP, my bad)

Comment: The arguments against this are usually pretty flimsy. It's useful because I might read a post with 15 comments on it, and after reading all 15 I've identified 3 or 4 that are helpful and deserve upvotes, so I get to spend 15 seconds patiently upvoting them one at a time. I never upvote comments midway because I don't know which comments are most useful until I've read them all; there might be a comment later that makes an earlier one totally unnecessary

Comment: @Wesley I agree, they are not worthless. But still, they are not first-class citizen. As I said, it would be nice to remove this limitation. However, I've seen many posts from SE staff (can't remember who, or which post) mentioning they would not make such a modification to the comment system.

Comment: If someone wanted to spam upvote a bunch of comments five seconds won't stop them, only slow them down, meanwhile it's annoying to the rest of us. Plus I doubt anyone ever went on a comment upvoting spree and even if they did, what difference did it make?

Comment: Looks like all these comments have been upvoted..

Comment: At least the timer doesn't reset like trying to post a second.

Comment: 5 seconds is quite brief. SO doesnt want u to get carpal tunnel synd.

Comment: I agree with Laf here. comments are just a side-show

Comment: @MartinSmith [But I thought you hated the 5 second rate limit on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200422/rate-limiting-on-voting-system/200423#comment639441_200423) now you're giving links for its justification? :P

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - I hate the 5 second rate limit on comment *cleanup*. Not the 5 second comment on upvoting them! Consistent with my earlier comment on this very post!

Comment: @MartinSmith ah I missed that

Comment: Wow.. long comment chain.  Seems like the #1 concern is that people would just vote without thinking, but I feel like the high rep part would cover that. The entire assumption of SE is that once you get to high reps, you understand how the system work and dont just mindlessly vote.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182697/comment-vote-throttling-makes-it-annoying-to-clean-up-obsolete-chat