# How to relinquish answers I've provided?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I'd like to remove hold of [all of my answers I hold on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132335/dauh-fhauc?tab=answers) while keeping their content in tact just in case they help anyone down the road. How can I go about doing this?

I see [deleted] users questions/answers frequently on StackOverflow, but I do not want to delete my account - just relinquish ownership of all my answers.

[Thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/233688).

Comment: If the answer is useful, why dissociate from it? If it's not useful, why not delete it?

Comment: Some of my answers are useful, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19324360/2132335) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18703741/2132335). My negative reputation here on Meta has led to people venturing into my StackOverflow account and down voting valid answers there. I'd rather just remove ownership of those answers (that may be helpful) than suffer the loss in reputation.

Comment: why do you think it is so? How do you know they were not being downvoted on their own?

Comment: Voting is anonymous, so you can never know for sure.

Comment: Whenever I make a controversial post here on Meta I get down voted on StackOverflow on _old posts_. Sure I do not know who is doing it, but to receive a lot of down votes on StackOverflow only when I post poorly received posts on Meta seems a little strange. But I regress. The question is about relinquishing ownership of answers, not about my past history or questions being downvoted on their own. I'd just like to _remove ownership completly_.

Comment: not sure about your first example, but the second one is basically just telling asker the problem (and not a solution) and a bunch of links. We don't like link-only answers here.

Comment: @DauhFhauc serial downvoting happens to everyone. Not having any answers is not a solution. Waiting until the serial downvoting reversal script kicks in is.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for your input. It isn't serial down voting I'm concerned about (the script won't help me there... I've [done it in the past myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196300/233688) and know that the script won't kick in for these instances), it's the sporadic down voting over a short time in relation to touchy posts here on Meta that I'm concerned about. I'd rather avoid the drama and disown my answers.

Comment: You could also search for questions to get a better idea of what the community does and doesn't like.  For instance, if you post a feature-request, *do* expect downvotes if someone disagrees about said feature being implemented.

Comment: But... I've seen times where someone merely addressed a perfectly legitimate concern (not a feature-request) and *still* received downvotes.  Rough world indeed.