# How many upvotes can I give this guy before I'm banned / penalized?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

[This guy is the developer of the C# port of the Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264294/peter-dettman?tab=answers) encryption library.  He is an occasional user but very smart and a great member of SO.

I want to upvote many of his answers so he can make better use of the site,  (he is currently below 1000) and so his answers stand out for both the casual observer and for anyone who does reporting via the data API.

So what shouldn't I do when upvoting this guy, and how close should I get to that limit?

Comment: What you shouldn't do is vote for his posts simply because he posted them.

Comment: @animuson I think that term is called the "Skeet effect", right?

Comment: Err...no, rather, it's called "serial voting" and, at best, will simply be reversed.

Comment: If you want to give him a big rep boost, find one of his _outstanding_ answers and give it a bounty.

Comment: You should probably read this: [I gave someone +200 rep and a Mortarboard Badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196300)

Comment: If he needs a boost so he can "make better use of this site", he should earn it just like everyone else, by participating here. Serial voting (up or down) is simply wrong on SO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Never, `while(true){printf("ever ,");}`

vote on a person. Vote on their posts. And as for telling the number of upvotes necessary to trigger the voting algorithm, that would defeat the purpose of the algorithm, wouldn't it, because if they release the algorithm, people would simply go one under that.

If you really want to get someone rep fast, select an exceptional answer that they have and give them a bounty on that one.

Comment: I hit a stack overflow while saying "ever" too many times..

Comment: @Travis you would only get a stack overflow with recursion. :P

Comment: @Doorknob I had recursion before, but I edited it back out

Answer (score 6):

Just to set a couple of things straight:

> so he can make better use of the site

You make the mistake of assuming that he is *active* on the site in the same way you or many other people are. Other than answering questions on the product he's written/ported (i.e. providing support) he looks to have little other interest in the site. He's asked **zero** questions and edited **one** tag.

> so his answers stand out for both the casual observer and for anyone who does reporting ...

Giving him more rep will not make his answers stand out any more than any other user. What will make his answers stand out is when they are accepted as the best answer.