# Is it serial voting if I "investigate" a user and vote on poor questions?

Tags: support, serial-voting

When I come across an awful question [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410796/add-element-in-arraylist), my [gut instinct](http://www.industrialscripts.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/taxidriver5.jpg) is to "investigate" that user to see what else they have posted.

All too often, the user has posted several poor questions that are en route to closure. I will typically add some comments and cast a down/close-vote here and there.

It occurs to me that this might be serial voting – a sudden rash of votes from one user to another. Do I risk being caught out by the serial voting algorithm?

Comment: It depends on the number of posts you downvote. If you keep it on the down-low, then the algorithm won't reverse it.

Comment: @Lix Reading that link, I feel like the Grinch in comparison :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones You're a mean one, Mr. Jones.

Comment: If you go hunting and looking at all of a users question that would count as serial voting. If you come across multiple questions by the same user in normal use of the site it should not count.

Comment: @joe - the problem is that it would be quite hard to differentiate between those two scenarios.

Comment: I often go on investigation but I only ever vote/flag based on them because that has oversight (other people have to agree with me),  unlike voting

Comment: @Lix Well in general if a user casts a lot of votes on someones question is it more likely that the went looking for questions to vote on or came across them in normal site use?

Comment: @joe - usually you are correct. There are some cases on high volume low turnover tags where you pretty much only see the same 5 users answering almost everything...

Comment: @JoeW Are you suggesting looking for questions to vote on is wrong? As someone who cares about the quality of the site, should I not take an interest in someone who's questions may be of below-acceptable standard?

Comment: @DuncanJones Targeting a user and voting up or down on their questions is considered serial voting and there is plenty of information on it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting.

Comment: @JoeW That link is focussed on malicious targeting (e.g. down-votes for no justified reason). My situation is quite different.

Comment: @DuncanJones Serial voting does not concern if there is a valid reason to upvote or downvote a lot of a users questions but rather the fact that one user has targeted another user to cast a chain of votes on their questions and answers. Here is an example that is talking of reversing upvotes that where done to thank a user http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/nicely-discouraging-serial-upvoting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible you'll be caught by the algorithm, so keep it reasonable.

Comment: "Reasonable" requires some definition to maintain any utility as a rule of thumb.