# Am I a victim of an automated serial upvoter script?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I was going through **Pekka's** [`post`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/nicely-discouraging-serial-upvoting) on Serial upvoting issues and I found this line

> serial upvoting as the expression of thanks from a (usually newbie)
>   user

But in my personal opinion what I think is *"Some people do it **intentionally**"*

Today I was hit by this script or probably a person.. It was raining upvotes .. 15 upvotes in 5 secs.

And this is the second time in 2 weeks. I sometimes lose interest on answering questions on Stack Overflow when such thing happens... Is there any remedy for this ?

Comment: Are you worried about possible negative consequences for being serial upvoted? If so, I don't think there are any.

Comment: Considering the timing of those upvotes, it sure does look like it was a script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?  Are you trying to find a way to avoid being a target of serial voting?  Or is it what @Stijn asked?

Comment: why would getting **upvotes** make you lose interest in answering questions?

Comment: @KateGregory if you are rep-capped and you don't know if those serial votes will be rolled back that could be discouraging.

Comment: @Kate getting a plus 10 is a little thrill. If you start to believe they probably aren't real you loose that

Comment: Shafik and Richard , read my inner mind btw :)

Comment: @Stijn: You'll be rep-capped for 24 hours and won't get reputation points from *valid* votes, either. This is indeed a consequence if you care about the points.

Comment: @AmalMurali According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131795/serial-up-voting-and-reputation-cap) you won't have lost the points after reversal happens.

Comment: @Stijn: As the accepted answer on that question says: "*The serial upvotes get reversed, all other votes count as normal **from that point on.***" - Any *legitimate* votes cast before the reversal won't count (as you'll get rep-capped soon after 20 votes).

Comment: @AmalMurali As a comment on that answer says: *your rep will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened at all. There will be no before/after, they cease to exist.*

Comment: If a serial upvote is reversed, your cap is **recalculated**. A serial upvoter cannot cheat you out of legitimate reputation gained this way.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i absolutely agree with you.

Comment: Related question about serial-downvoter script: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279922/is-stack-exchange-able-to-be-hacked-through-the-javascript-console

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When the serial upvote is reversed, your reputation is recalculated *as if the serial votes were never applied*.

This means that a reputation cap will be recalculated too, you will *still* get your legitimately earned reputation from normal upvotes.

So, if you received 15 serial votes, and 10 regular votes, on the day itself you'll be reputation capped and receive 200 points. When the reversal script has run, you'll have received the normal 10 votes only on that day and earned 100 points.

The bottom line is that you'll not be penalized for serial upvotes, be it from an innocent newbie fan or a malicious user hoping to force the reputation cap on you unfairly.

Comment: I think the last time this happened to me (which was a few weeks before), the reputation points for the day I was rep-capped was not re-added (I could be wrong, though).

Comment: @AmalMurali: This has happened to me a few times; the cap *is recalculated*.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification, @Martijn. Totally unrelated question: is there a way to find on which days you were serially (down|up)-voted?

Comment: I don't think so; you could check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation but I think the votes are scrubbed from that list.

Comment: Martin thanks for the answer. Just a simple question. Since I reached rep limit , when some legitimate user finds my answer and upvotes it , I won't get any votes (which we already know) . So when the reversal script runs the next day.. will I get the 10 reps for the legitimate post or It will be just gone in the air ?

Comment: That is what my answer has been telling you. If without the serial votes you should have earned the +10 you get the +10 after recalculating.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I should have answer some questions after hitting the rep cap to test that out if that really works. I hope you are not wrong. Accepted the answer **+1** (Nice answer).